# SQL Server cursor is not looping although there are lots of records in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Although `SELECT id, also FROM names WHERE isnull(also,'')<>''1` is returning 2000+ results, the following cursor not looping and I'm getting:

```
@count = 0
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @id BIGINT, @name NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE @aslo TABLE (id INT, name NVARCHAR(100))

DECLARE name_cur CURSOR FOR 
     (SELECT id, also 
      FROM names 
      WHERE ISNULL(also, '') <> '')

DECLARE @count INT = 0

OPEN name_cur

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   SET @count = @count + 1

   INSERT INTO @aslo (id, name)
       SELECT @id, * 
       FROM string_split(@name, ',')

   FETCH NEXT FROM name_cur INTO @id, @name;  
END  

CLOSE name_cur;  
DEALLOCATE name_cur;

SELECT @count
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @aslo a
```

Comment: You `open` the cursor and check `@@Fetch_Status` without using `fetch` to get the first row, if any.

Comment: @HABO Yessssss you are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is much simpler to do this without a cursor.  This seems to be equivalent to what you want to do:

```
INSERT INTO @aslo (id, name)
    SELECT n.id, ss.value as name
    FROM names n CROSS APPLY
         string_split(n.name, ',') ss;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df3656bb96a58e196a4692ef1d00b545) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I you know sql well then yes this is easier ;). however I'm getting `'string_split' is not a recognized function name.` and also `the multi-part identifier "ss.name" could not be bound`

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani . . . Uh, `string_split()` comes from **your** code.

Comment: but it is a sql function

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani . . . I always forget that you cannot redefine the names of the columns returned from a built-in function.  The `ss(name)` is the cause of the problem.  I fixed the answer.